# Existence of a special vertex in a special DAG

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Suppose we're given a Directed Acyclic Graph $G$ with $L$ leaves such that every non-leaf vertex has out-degree $2$. Let $r(v)$ the number of leaves reachable starting at vertex $v$. $G$ is such that it has a root vertex $v_0$ with $r(v_0) = L$.

How does one prove that given these conditions $G$ also has a vertex $v$ such that $\dfrac{L}{3}\leq r(v)\leq\dfrac{2L}{3}$?

As we go from the root $v_0$ towards any one leaf $l_0$ we trace out a path along which $r(\cdot)$ either decreases or stays the same and overall it decreases from $L$ to $1$. This is true for all such paths. But how does one prove the existence of a vertex with $\dfrac{L}{3}\leq r(v)\leq\dfrac{2L}{3}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting at $v_0$, walk along the path which always goes from a vertex $v$ to the out-neighbor $w$ with the larger value of $r$.

If $v$ has edges to $w_1$ and $w_2$, then $r(v) \le r(w_1) + r(w_2)$, so in particular $\max\{r(w_1), r(w_2)\} \ge \frac12 r(v)$. So along our path, we can't jump directly from a vertex $v$ with $r(v) > \frac{2L}{3}$ to a vertex $w$ with $r(w) < \frac{L}{3}$.

However, we start above $\frac {2L}3$ and we must end up below $\frac L3$ at some point, because we end at a leaf where $r=1$. So we must have visited a vertex $v$ with $r(v)$ in the range $[\frac{L}{3}, \frac{2L}{3}]$.